# dist-upgrade from Debian 7 (wheezy) to 8 (jessie) results in 'Failed to execute operation' errors

Tags: debian, dpkg, systemd, upgrade

After upgrading Debian 7 (wheezy) to 8 (jessie), any system critical action results in one of the following messages appearing:

```
Failed to execute operation: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Failed to get properties: Connection timed out
```

Last time this happened on my local test machine (which was using sid), it was unable to boot after that. It would just get stuck.

How could this issue be resolved?
Would simply downgrading to the last version work?

Comment: test `dpkg -a --configure`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh that results in: "Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out" and "Failed to get properties: Connection timed out". On a side note, there are a ton of defunct processes that all apparently belong to pid 1. Most of these are user processes, which should not belong to pid 1.

Comment: Full result of above command: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zp1LPN3f

Comment: I hate upgrade installations as for me they always have problems.  When making major version upgrades, my preference is to do a full reinstall from scratch.  If you want to try the upgrade again, restore from backups and retry it, I would not try to salvage a system that broken.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution Test 1:** Downgrade to earlier versions.
**Result:** Broken System (not bootable)

**Solution Test 2:** Restore from backup, update, upgrade, dist-upgrade.
(upgrade step can be left out, no change in final result)
**Result:** Broken System (not bootable)

**Solution Test 3:** Reinstall Debian 7, edit sources.list to include jessie, update, upgrade, dist-upgrade.
(upgrade step can be left out, no change in final result)
**Result:** Broken System (bootable, but can't login)

In the end, i just went with a full reinstall. I had downloaded a backup from yesterday containing all the changed configuration files only, so things were easily set up again.

Hopefully this saves some future user some time.